# Java auto-growing array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am attempting to make a program (just for fun), which takes in a user input and password, and adds them to arrays. But since I don't have a defined number of users and passwords, I want to make it auto grow by doing something like this:

```
static String[] passes = new String[i];
```

and then somewhere i++;

Something like so: (inputUser is a string which was given a value by a scanner)

```
private static void Update() {
    i++;
    user[i] = inputUser;
}
```

Result:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

I tried that but it didn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

**Code was requested:**

```
package users.main;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main { 

static int i = 0;
static List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>; // << Also highlighted red. Do i need ()?
//     ^^^ Error
static String[] passes = new String[i];
static String inputUser = null;
static String inputPass = null;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")         // <--- Eclipse wanted me to add this?....
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = sc.nextLine();

    switch (userInput) {
    case "adduser":
        AddUser();
        break;  

    default:

        System.out.println("Unknown command");
        main(args);
    }
}
```

> **UPDATE: I have changed the array to a list, but am still getting some errors.**

Comment: Look into ArrayList or LinkedList. They (and other data structures) grow as more elements are added.

Comment: Arrays are fixed in size, array size can not be changed. To do so you need to create a new array with new size and copy previous array element into new array. Or you can use collection classes (like ArrayList or LinkedList) provided in java.

Comment: You have used wrong List. You should use java.util.List

Comment: Yes you do need the `()` at the end to ArrayList (ie. `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a collection such as ArrayList so that it can grow dynamically. Another recommendation, introduce a new data type to hold your userName and password information.

Here is a simple program that may help you.

```
package stackoverflow1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class User {
    private String mUserName;
    private String mPassword;

    public User(String userName, String password) {
        mUserName = userName;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    public String getUserName() { return mUserName; }
    public String getPasword() { return mPassword; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String info = String.format("Name: %s Pwd: %s", mUserName, mPassword);
        return info;
    }
}

public class Main {
    static List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();        

    static void addUser(Scanner scanner) {
        String userName, password;

        println("UserName: ");
        userName = scanner.nextLine();
        println("Password: ");
        password = scanner.nextLine();

        println("Adding a new user now.");
        users.add(new User(userName, password));        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            println("Add user name and password. Type quit when you are done.");
            String userInput = scanner.nextLine();

            switch (userInput) {
                case "adduser":
                    addUser(scanner);
                    break;

                case "quit":
                    done = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    println("Unknown input!");
            }
        }

        println("--- Users Information ---");
        users.forEach(user -> println(user.toString()));
    }

    static void println(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Array you can use ArrayList. ArrayList is a Kind of Dynamic Array. it will grow automatically once the it reaches to the size.

to use ArrayList do this.

```
static List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

private static void Update() {
   users.add(inputUser)
}
```

Comment: Eclipse doesn't like that. Error: The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: Can you paste you code? Can you check if you have imported the correct List class from Collections? it should be  import java.util.List;

Comment: I'll post most of the code, including main just in case.

Comment: Yeah , so as i said , you are importing the wrong class. Instead of "import java.awt.List;"
 you need to import "import java.util.List;".

Comment: Well that did fix the list error. There appears to be another, however, after <String> there is a red underline just before the ";". I attempted adding parenthesis, it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, i edited my answer. it should "new ArrayList<String>()". Another thing  is , Make sure that you have defined list as static as you were accessing  list inside static function. please see my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Use *[Collections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm)* instead. You can use ArrayList for an auto-growing array.

Comment: welcome and happy coding :)

Comment: Adding a collection is right, so I will +1 to just to eliminate -1 for this user.

Comment: yes that is what I am saying :)

Comment: I added my own answer also to make this more understandable for the new developers.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you can use collections. In your case you're interested in dynamic lists, so you'll like [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which uses arrays internally to grow. Specifically, doubles its size each time is full, to get an amortized constant time on addition methods.

[Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) need to be imported from `java.util` package.

You can use ArrayList in this way:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // You've to add parentheses, because this is an initialization from the empty constructor of ArrayList class.
list.add("Some object of the generic type");
```

Since Java 7 you can instantiate generic classes with the diamond operator, which infers the types:

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Check Java API for more methods you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You did not use proper way to create an ArrayList object. Also you need to import java.util.ArrayList class. Checkout the below code:

```
package users.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main { 

    static int i = 0;
    static List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>(); //ArrayList<String>; was wrong here
    static String[] passes = new String[i];
    static String inputUser = null;
    static String inputPass = null;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = sc.nextLine();

        switch (userInput) {
        case "adduser":
            AddUser();
            break;  

        default:

            System.out.println("Unknown command");
            main(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I couldn't accept yours, someone else had the same answer before you.

Comment: Thats fine, the other answer is more complete.